# absolute-positioned objects added via jQuery are not positioning properly!

Tags: jquery, dynamic, css-position

I'm dynamically adding some `li`s to an unordered list using jQuery.  They are positioned absolutely (using the `style` param on each `li`), but when they are added to the page they aren't in the right positions, even though when I check them with Firebug or Chrome's element inspector, all the values are correct.

Also note that the `li`s are using the jQuery draggable and resizeable classes.

you can see it here: http://bit.ly/5HfegZ

This is the script that adds the `li`s to the page (from xml file)

```
 //load saved board  
      var savedBoard = getParameterByName("open");
      if (savedBoard != ""){

       $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "saved/" + savedBoard + ".xml",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success: function(xml) {

                      $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                          var openTag = $(this).find('openTag').text();
                      openTag = openTag.replace(/%3C/g, "<");
                      openTag = openTag.replace(/%2F/g, "/");
                      openTag = openTag.replace(/%3E/g, ">");
                          var media = $(this).find('media').text();
                      media = media.replace(/%3C/g, "<");
                      media = media.replace(/%2F/g, "/");
                      media = media.replace(/%3E/g, ">");

                          $('#other').append(openTag + "<div class='inners'>" + media + "</div><div class='boxMenu'><img class='star' src='img/gold_star.gif' alt='Favorite' /><img class='delete' src='img/minus.gif' alt='Delete'/><p></p></div></li>");
                          $("li", "#other").draggable();
                          $("li", "#other").resizable({ transparent: true, handles: 'all' });
                          menustuff();
                          checkColour();
                      });

                  }
              });

      }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="other" class="ui-widget-header">
```

XML:

```
<item n="0"> 
<openTag>%3Cli runat='server' title='0' class='ui-widget-content' style='z-index:16;width:250px;height:150px;top:187 px;left:135px;'%3E</openTag> 
<media>%3Cimg class="imaged" src="http:%2F%2Fimages.websnapr.com%2F?size=s&amp;key=bOJhv6ljQ0aq&amp;url=http:%2F%2Fwww.cancerpartnersuk.org" alt=""&gt;</media>
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to post some of your JQuery and HTML to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found out that it wasent displaying correctly because the jQuery ui.resizable class was `position: relative;` i just set that to `position: absolute;` and all was well again.